# Finding sum of all bytes in a buffer

Tags: java, arrays, checksum, bytebuffer

I am working on something and I am required to calculate checksum with every data sent. This checksum is the Lower 2 bytes of the 4 byte sum of all the bytes

Assume I have the data as:

```
Bytebuffer buffer = Bytebuffer.allocate(128); // assume i have filled buffer with some data
```

Below is how I am find the sum of all bytes and then getting the lower of 2 bytes.

```
byte array = buffer.array();
int checksum = 0;

for(byte b : array){
  checksum += (int)b
}

checksum = (checksum & 0xff00ff) + ((checksum >> 0x08) & 0xff00ff);
short result = (short) (checksum + (checksum >> 0x10));
```

However, the application listening for this data tells me the checksum is wrong. What could be wrong in my logic of thinking? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Don't read from the buffer's backing `array()`. You should not normally access that array directly. It ignores the buffer's limit, and position. Instead, use the `get()` methods. A bulk get:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
buffer.get(bytes);
```

or individual gets:

```
while (buffer.hasRemaining()) {
    checksum += buffer.get() & 0xff;
}
```

Note that if you've filled the buffer up with `put()` calls, you need to call [`flip()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#flip--).

> After a sequence of channel-read or *put* operations, invoke this method to prepare for a sequence of channel-write or relative *get* operations.

Comment: Thanks, it seems like the original buffer is being modified though. Is there a way not to that?

Comment: That's how `ByteBuffer`s work. They're like files with positioning markers that update as you read and write. It's not something you should try to avoid.